# How can I search in MongoDB ISODate field from Python?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have an API from which I receive a query. This API is in Python.

I call it from a django app (views.py). Then, I want to query my MongoDB collection, using mongoengine:

```
api_response = requests.get("http://*******", {'query':query}) #We call the API
json_resp = api_response.json()
person = Person.objects(__raw__=json_resp).to_json() #We search for the json_query in the DB (raw) and the output is JSON
```

It works fine but I have a problem with dates... Indeed, my Person model is as follow:

```
class Person(DynamicDocument):

    # Meta Variables
    meta = {
        'collection':'personsExample'
        }

    #Document variables
    PersonID = models.CharField(max_length = 6)
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length = 6) #male/female
    BirthDate = models.DateField()
    CitizenCountryCode = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
```

My personsExample collection was imported via mongoimport from a CSV file:

```
mongoimport --host localhost --db persons --collection personsExample --type csv --file reducedPersonsExtract.csv --headerline
```

As the birth dates were set as string, I have converted them using:

```
db.personsExample.find().forEach(function(el){el.BirthDate = new ISODate(el.BirthDate); db.personsExample.save(el)})
```

The problem I have now is that it gives BirthDate field as follow:

```
"BirthDate" : ISODate("1970-12-21T00:00:00Z")
```

But in my json query, date is stored as

```
datetime.datetime(1970,12,21,0,0,0).isoformat()
```

Which gives:

```
{
    "BirthDate": "1970-12-21T00:00:00"
}
```

Thus, the query doesn't work, I would need to make my query with

```
{
    "BirthDate": ISODate"1970-12-21T00:00:00Z"
}
```

(But I can't create such objects (ISODate) with Python... )
Or to find another way to store the date in MongoDB.

Would you happen to know how I could solve my problem please?

Comment: You don't need to create ISODates for the PyMongo driver, you can use native Python types, as per [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html#documents).

Comment: Drop the `.isoformat()` just use the date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the problem is that if I don't use the .isoformat, I can't serialize my response in JSON...

Comment: @LM91 that doesn't make sense... your response is _already_ serialized as json and is being deserialized to python objects (when you call the `json()` method of response). It's then being passed to mongoengine `__raw__` as a python dict as it should be... it's at this point that you should make sure your dict contains python dates rather than string or `ISODate`

Comment: @ Anentropic Sorry, I meant that I can do the following: `person = Person.objects(__raw__=json_resp).to_json()`, because `to_json` won't work for `datetime.datetime`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have succeeded to to what I wanted to. In fact, I don't convert dates to ISODate in the DB, I store them as string "YYYY-MM-DD". Then, I format the date in my API (which sends the JSON query to the App which uses MongoDB) :

```
my_dict['BirthDate'] =  datetime.datetime(YYYY,MM,DD).isoformat()
```

Then, in my App :

```
json_resp = api_response.json() #Deserialization of the response

json_resp['BirthDate'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(json_resp['BirthDate'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
```

It may not be the best solution but it works.